# Rails + React.js : Hiding information from view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs

In a Rails + React app I have an index page where I map over all the data. This works but if you inspect the element react dumps the entire contents of the rails object into the root react element. This could potentionally be information I dont want users to have access to. What is the best way to obscure this information from the user?
Thanks

[image]

**Microposts Controller**

```
def index
    @microposts = Micropost.all
end
```

**Index.erb**

```
<%= react_component 'Microposts', { microposts: @microposts } %>
```

**Microposts.es6.jsx**

```
class Microposts extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return(
        <div>
            {this.props.microposts.map(function(x){
                return(
                    <p key={x.id}>{x.email}</p>
                )
            })}
        </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could filter attributes showing by:

```
<%= react_component 'Microposts', { microposts: @microposts.as_json(only: [:id, :email]) } %>
```